# How to apply Keras Conv1D over 3D dimensional input?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, keras

**Context**: I'm predicting whether a machine will break down within 1 hour, and I have sensors located at 4 different parts of the machine, which give me historical readings of different metrics. Concretely, for each sensor, I have a time series of 100 seconds with 10 metrics. I'm modeling this with 1dcnn, which is quite simple using Keras:

```
# pseudo code 
time_series_inputs = Input(shape=(time_series_length=100, num_features=10,))   
conv_branch = Conv1D(num_filters, kernel_size)(time_series_inputs)
```

Now the model only uses one time series, and the information of the other sensors should help the model. One way to use the other time series is to directly add them up along the feature dimension, so that my input is (100, 40).

However, I'm considering another way to process the data: **I want to apply the 1d conv over time shared across all the four sensors**, and now the input is 3D, could be (4, 100, 10), for example.

Now the problem is that Keras Conv1D layer only accepts 2d input, and I have no idea how to achieve what I described above. It's possible to use the Conv2D layer, but I suspect whether it fits my purpose.

Any information will help.